# changed? call on properties not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model class as shown below:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user;
    attr_accessible :price

 before_save :check_if_price_changed
    after_save :notify_about_price_change

    def check_if_price_changed
       if (price.changed?) then
               @price_changed = true
           else
               @price_changed = false
           end
    end

....
```

I want to record if the price of the product changed before I save it to the database.  Then I have a routine that will do the notification once the product has been persisted successfully with the new price.  But I get the following error when I try to check if the price attribute is dirty:

```
undefined method `changed?' for 20:Fixnum
```

Is that method not supported out of the box in rails 3.1?  Am I calling it incorrectly or in the incorrect layer (model vs controller)?

Comment: Is 'price' a column name in the prices products table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return a boolean reflecting whether or not the price value has changed.

```
def check_if_price_changed
   self.price_changed?
end
```

Have a look at the [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) documentation.

Comment: thanks. I had seen that article but I thought it was needed for normal classes and not the ones that inherit from ActiveRecord.  But making the change you suggested got it going. Mucho Gracias!